# Do I need to specify an UID in my Dockerfile when running in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Having this dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch
CMD ["cat", "/tmp/secrets.txt"]
```

I can then run

```
docker run -v /etc/shadow:/tmp/secrets.txt spycontainer
```

Even if I am not root, I will be able to see `/etc/shadow` !

How is Kubernetes avoiding somebody doing this? Do I need to make sure that every image has the UID in the dockerfile??

Comment: (You can explicitly specify `-u 0` to force a container to run with a user ID of 0 [root], even if the image has an alternate `USER`; and you can use the same technique to edit host files as well.  This is a key reason Docker requires `sudo` access by default.)

Comment: I do not need to do `sudo` in my laptop to run the previous container. that was what surprised me. I do not have permissions to do cat to the shadow file, but i can do it with the example i posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kubernetes you can use [pod security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod)

When you run a container without any security context, the entrypoint command with run as **root**. For example

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
/ # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sh
```

If you use security context like following

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
```

Using `runAsUser` you can modify the user id of the process inside a container. For example

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/security/security-context.yaml
$ kubectl exec -it security-context-demo -- sh
/ $ ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 1000      0:00 sleep 1h
    6 1000      0:00 sh
```